# Creating native ios framework(. framework) and Android jar using flutter project

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

Is it possible to create ios framework or Android jar from a flutter project? I mean if I'm having a Flutter project, I'm sure i can create a flutter package out of it and use it around any flutter projects. But is it possible to get .framework (for swift) and .jar(for Android) too so that I can just use that framework file in xcode in native swift app?

Comment: Look at Flutter `Add2App`.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps explains the options for combining Flutter with native iOS or Android apps.

Comment: is it possible to generate .framwork from a dart project is my question.